# How to open infowindow after clicking on symbol associated with a polyline

Tags: google-maps, symbols, infowindow, google-polyline

I am working on a vehicle tracking solution. I have a polyline on which I animate a symbol(that looks like car) to make it look like car is moving on map. When my user clicks on the car, I want to open a infowindow to show driver's name and mobile number.

I can open infowindow if a marker is clicked, but I don't know how to do the same for a sybmol moving on polyline.

Comment: you can use a marker as symbol

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
   marker.setPosition(latlng);
```

for change position

and  assign to marker an icon like your symbol

```
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: feature.position,
        icon: your_symbol_image.png,
        map: map
      });
```

simply get the postion you need  and open the infowindow  ..

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: "my infowindow text content"});
   infowindow.setPosition(your_lat_lng);
   infowindow.open(map);
```

Comment: The icons of marker are static, but symbols can rotate on any angle. When road turns, the symbol on my polyline turns accordingly giving expression that car is turning. This can't be done if I use static icons on marker. I must use symbol moving on polyline.

Comment: or you can assign a infowindow to polyline and set the  position for infowindow

Comment: mPolyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
            path: path, //path on which the car needs to move
            strokeColor: 'black',
            icons: [{
                icon: car, //This car is a symbol
                offset: '0%'
            }]
        });    

the car moves on this polyline by the following code:
var icons = carInstance.snappedPolyline.get('icons');
            icons[0].offset = (count / 2) + '%';
            carInstance.snappedPolyline.set('icons', icons);
When we change the offset, the car moves from beginning of polyline till the end.

Comment: See example code by google here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-symbol-animate

In this scenario, can you tell me how to add infowindow